# Discord.py Verification System

Tags: discord.py

I am making a verification system where if you type `!verify "1. John 2. Mr. Teacher 3. Somewhere 4. Freshman 5. The Cool Mascot"` it will send an embed in a channel looking like this: https://gyazo.com/ab808bafcd4a5f3ed05f63e007da20c1.
If someone reacts with the checkmark I want to dm the user saying that they have been accepted and if they get denied it will send a dm saying they have been denied but I seem to not get a dm when reacting and they do not get the Member role right after, and there are no tracebacks.

Code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def verify(ctx, message):
  logem = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red())
  logem.set_author(name=f"Verification Request!")
  logem.add_field(name="User", value=f"{ctx.author.mention}")
  logem.add_field(name="Application", value=f"{message}")
  logem.set_footer(text=f"React with ✅ to accept the application and ❌ to deny the application",
                           icon_url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/Exclamation_mark_red.png/50px-Exclamation_mark_red.png")
  logemlog = bot.get_channel(820840787645956123)
  msg = await logemlog.send(embed=logem)
  await msg.add_reaction('✅')
  await msg.add_reaction('❌')

async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    msgid = await ctx.fetch_message(msgID)
    ourMessageID = msgid

    if ourMessageID == payload.message_id:
      member = payload.member
      guild = member.guild

      emoji = payload.emoji.name
    if emoji == '✅':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Member")
      print ('Accepted Someones Application')
      em = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red())
      em.set_author(name="Verified!")
      em.set_footer(text=f"You Have Been Accepted Into The Official WHS Discord Server!",
                           icon_url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/Exclamation_mark_red.png/50px-Exclamation_mark_red.png")
      await member.send("You have been accepted!")
      await member.add_roles(role)
    elif emoji == '❌':
      em = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red())
      em.add_field(name="Denied!", value=f"{message}")
      em.set_footer(text=f"You Have Been Denied Access Into The Official WHS Discord Server!",
                           icon_url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/Exclamation_mark_red.png/50px-Exclamation_mark_red.png")
      await ctx.member.send("You have been Denied!")
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using `on_raw_reaction_add` instead of `wait_for`? Also you're not adding the `bot.event` decorator

Comment: Oh, I didn't even ven realize I didn't have the `bot.event` decorator, also I tried using wait for but it would also just spit out an error

Comment: How is the event supposed to work without the decorator then? Also `wait_for` is a much better solution

Comment: Ok, ill try it, and ill let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead of async def on_raw_reaction_add:

```py
def check(reaction, user):
        return reaction.emoji in ['✅', '❌'] and user == ctx.author
while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)

        except Exception as e:

            print(e)
        else:
            if reaction.emoji == '✅':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Member")
                print ('Accepted Someones Application')
                em = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red())
                em.set_author(name="Verified!")
                em.set_footer(text=f"You Have Been Accepted Into The Official WHS Discord Server!",
                    icon_url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/Exclamation_mark_red.png/50px-Exclamation_mark_red.png")
                await member.send("You have been accepted!")
                await member.add_roles(role)
           if reaction.emoji == '❌':
               em = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red())
               em.add_field(name="Denied!", value=f"{message}")
               em.set_footer(text=f"You Have Been Denied Access Into The Official WHS Discord Server!",
                           icon_url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/Exclamation_mark_red.png/50px-Exclamation_mark_red.png")
               await ctx.member.send("You have been Denied!")
```

Test it and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, happy to help you!